# Greek-Symbol Theta on Stainless-Steel Nut?

Tags: fastener, stainless

I am trying to understand everything I can about some stainless-steel nuts that I have come across. I have already researched and found information on the characters at the bottom of each nut, but I cannot find information on the symbol that looks like Theta at the top. So, my question is,

**What does the ~Theta symbol mean on these stainless-steel nuts?**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to guess it's the manufacturers' logo.

> In addition to the indicated grade marking, all grades, except A563 grades O, A and B, must be marked for manufacturer identification. –[americanfastener.com](http://www.americanfastener.com/astm-sae-and-iso-grade-markings-for-steel-fasteners/)

Comment: I think you have a `Fxxx grade D` nut, so no, the identification rule applies. *"all grades except..."*. The keyword *Theta* yielded me little results amongst fastener companies.

Comment: Apologies for removing my note that you replied to. Anyway, I think you are correct that it is not a Theta symbol; I found this 'fastener identification guide' that may be helpful to future readers:   http://www.idot.illinois.gov/Assets/uploads/files/Doing-Business/Manuals-Guides-&-Handbooks/Highways/Materials/Metals/fasteneridentificationguide.pdf    It has a company symbol on page ~42 for a company named 'MNP Manufacturing Corp.' that I think may be a match.

Comment: Finding an actual picture of a MNP bolt, clearly showing its markings is proving difficult. I'm going to go ahead and say, sure ;p –Nice link for identifying manufacturers.

Comment: Same here. I also tried the same strategy , but have not found one in Google images. Btw, Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is following this, I emailed MNP and they responded, "MNP does not manufacture nuts."